# How to create thumbnail of a video using FFMpegCore?

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg

I have a web application, where I need to create thumbnails or images taking the first frame of a video. There are already many examples of this, but I can't find anything that solves my problem. I am using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FFMpegCore/), but I'm finding it challenging, because I need to read the video and write the result using streams directly. This is my code:

```
var videoStream = file.OpenReadStream();
var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
FFMpegArguments
    .FromPipeInput(new StreamPipeSource(videoStream))
    .OutputToPipe(new StreamPipeSink(outputStream), options => options
    .WithFrameOutputCount(1)
    .ForceFormat("jpeg")
    )
    .ProcessSynchronously();
```

Which leads me to the error: `Pipe is broken.` According to [here](https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore/issues/130), the error is related to the fact that the output format cannot be known. Only by adding the `.ForceFormat("opus")` option does the error disappear, but I understand that the `opus` format is for audio. Could any expert help me find the solution or tell me how I should do it? Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE**

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1397578/1848728) where it explains how to correctly use ffmpeg pipes. I modified my code and now it is:

```
var videoStream = file.OpenReadStream();
var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
FFMpegArguments
    .FromPipeInput(new StreamPipeSource(videoStream))
    .OutputToPipe(new StreamPipeSink(outputStream), opt => opt
    .Seek(TimeSpan.Zero)
    .Resize(650, 390)
    .WithFrameOutputCount(1)
    .WithVideoCodec(VideoCodec.Png)
    .ForceFormat("image2pipe")
    )
    .ProcessSynchronously();
```

The arguments indicated in the answer `ffmpeg -i - -ss 00:00:3 -s 650x390 -vframes 1 -c:v png -f image2pipe -` are very similar to those generated by my code `-i "\\.\pipe\FFMpegCore_9dd64" -ss 00:00:00.000 -s 650x390 -vframes 1 -c:v png -f image2pipe "\\.\pipe\FFMpegCore_997f4" -y`, and even so, errors persists.
​

Comment: If the stream approach continues to fail, you might want to try a different method such as first saving the video to a temporary file, extracting the frame, and then reading it into a MemoryStream if necessary.

Comment: I have already tried saving the image to a temporary file, and it works. But it is precisely what I want to avoid.

Comment: And if you don't want to save it then what are you looking for? Can you clarify that temp file works but what you're actually looking for? Clearly the error isn't the issue if you can write to file? What is your surrounding code as well since you're working with streams here?

Comment: I need exactly what I explain in my question. What has worked for me is to have the input video in the storage to create the image, specifying the storage as the output location. When I say "temporary", I mean that when I save the image in the cloud, (azure storage for example), I no longer need either the video file or the image file. I find it unnecessary to have to save it when FromPipeInput and OutputToPipe exist. Thankss!

Comment: Unfortunately some ffmpeg/ffprobe functionalities are not available when using streams/pipes mainly because most formats requires seeking to get some info and that operation is not available on pipes. As you noticed the best you can do is to write a temp file, pass it to ffmpeg then delete it

Comment: @MatteoUmili What if I'm happy with it being the first frame of the video?